# How to find and stop what has locked a serial port in Linux

Tags: python, linux, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to connect to a makerbot 3d printer using pyserial. The part of the code for connecting that's giving me trouble is this:

```
import serial
file = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 115200, timeout=1)
```

When I run it as is (ie. just python), then I get:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM1'
```

So I run it with super user privelleges (sudo python) and I get this back:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: pid 3516 could not open port /var/lock/LCK..ttyACM1: locked by PID 1054
```

So I guess the device is locked by something. But how can I find out what is locking it, and how to stop it?

Comment: You can look for PID 1054 using `ps -aux | grep 1054` and see what program that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
lsof /dev/ttyACM1
```

You may need to grab lsof, as it may not be installed by default on your dist.

Per lsof's man page:

> Lsof lists on its standard output file information about files opened by processes 
>   [...] An open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain socket.) A specific file or all the files in a file system may be selected by path.

Comment: Can you explain what this does?